# Fatal error in database connection with php

Tags: php

Pls can someone help me fix this error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function `mysql_connect()` in C:\xampp\htdocs\library1\library\connection.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\library1\login.php(39): include() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\library1\library\connection.php on line 2

Comment: mysql-extension is __deprecated and removed__ in php7. Unless you use some legacy code - __forget__ about `mysql`, otherwise see comment above.

Answer (score 0):

try to use mysqli_connect() instead of mysql_connect() statement. It is an improved version of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

mysql functions have been removed in PHP7 XAMPP So, Please Use PDO Or My_Sqli To Avoid This.

> **PDO** will work on 12 different database systems, where as **MySQLi** will only work with MySQL databases.

**PDO:** https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

**MY_Sqli:** https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

**NOTE:**

> **mysql_connect** — Open a connection to a MySQL Server  Warning  This
>   extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.